# Find all views that contain a certain table or column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, legacy

In a legacy database infrastructure, how do I best find views that access a certain table or column? I'm currently refactoring certain tables (i.e. delete unused columns) and I want to find all views that still rely on those columns and will break, if I remove the columns.

Is there any tool/feature to search through all view definitions in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: alter table drop column restrict?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like function `dependent_views`, code below. Example usage:

```
select dependent_views('CUSTOMER_NAME', 'CUSTOMERS') list from dual

Output:
LIST
-----------------
SCOTT.V_PERSONS
```

Function searches dependendent views in `ALL_DEPENDENCIES`, next searches `TEXT` column from `ALL_VIEWS` for occurence of column_name.

Note: Because all_dependences may not contain full data of dependent objects (for instance when view was created by execute immediate) - my function may not find this object.
Also if `column_name` is substring of other column - function may return to many views.

```
create or replace function dependent_views
  (i_column varchar2, i_table varchar2, i_owner varchar2 default USER)
  return varchar2 is

  o_ret varchar2(4000) := '';
  v_text long := '';
begin
  for o in (
    select * from all_dependencies 
      where referenced_name  = upper(i_table)
        and referenced_owner = upper(i_owner)
        and type = 'VIEW')
  loop
    begin
      select text into v_text from all_views 
        where view_name = o.name and owner = o.owner;
    exception when no_data_found then 
      null;
    end;
    if upper(v_text) like '%'||upper(i_column)||'%' then
      o_ret := o_ret||o.owner||'.'||o.name||'  ';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return o_ret;
end dependent_views;
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I best find views that access a certain table

You could query the **[USER|ALL|DBA]_DEPENDENCIES** view.

```
SELECT name ,
  type ,
  referenced_name ,
  referenced_type
FROM user_dependencies
WHERE TYPE   = 'VIEW' 
AND NAME = '<VIEW_NAME>'
AND referenced_type = '<TABLE_NAME'>;
```

To get the result for all the views at once, remove the filter `NAME = '<VIEW_NAME>'`.

For example,

```
SQL> column name format a15
SQL> column type format a15
SQL> column referenced_name format a15
SQL> column referenced_type format a15
SQL> SELECT name ,
  2    type ,
  3    referenced_name ,
  4    referenced_type
  5  FROM user_dependencies
  6  WHERE TYPE   = 'VIEW';

NAME            TYPE            REFERENCED_NAME REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
EMP_CUSTOM_VIEW VIEW            EMP             TABLE
EMP_VIEW        VIEW            EMP             TABLE

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you search for all views that access certain table, this might help:

```
select 
    name, 
    type, 
    referenced_name, 
    referenced_type
from user_dependencies 
where type = 'VIEW' 
    and referenced_type = 'TABLE'
```